# Converting <T>[][] to <T>[] by extracting 1 element from the inner array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

Is there a potential 1 liner that allows me to create a new 1 dimensional array from a certain index of the inner array of the 2D?

Example take the first element of each inner array:

```
double[][] array2D = new double[10][] // with inner arrays say double[5]
double[] array1D = new double[10];

for (int i=0; i<array2D.Length; i++)
{
    array1D[i] = array2D[i][0];
}
```

Comment: It seems to me you already have a 2 liner...

Comment: hehe I'd like to avoid loops, so let's say a 1 liner :p

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<2dArray.Lengt; i++) 1dArray[i] = 2dArray[i][0];` 1 liner :D

Comment: something like `2dArray.Select(a => a[0]).ToArray();` ?

Comment: That for-loop is pretty good. No need to change it, imo. But you can use Enumerable.Range(0, array2d.Length) if you really want to. (and btw 2darray is not a valid variable name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just use LINQ. That won't "avoid loops" in terms of execution, but it'll avoid a loop in *your* source code:

```
// 1dArray isn't a valid identifier...
var singleArray = jaggedArray.Select(x => x[0]).ToArray();
```

Note that this relies on it being a jagged array (an array of arrays). It will *not* do what you expect for true multi-dimensional (rectangular) arrays.

Or slightly more efficiently:

```
var singleArray = Array.ConvertAll(jaggedArray, x => x[0]);
```

That's more efficient because it knows the output size to start with, and builds the array directly - but it's a bit less idiomatic than using LINQ these days (which is more generally applicable to *all* sequences, not just arrays).

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am indeed looking for something like this :)